# Views Rules in edited system node template

Tags: rules, panels

For learning purposes, I'm working on a project which uses Rules Links.

My first attempt had a Rules Link on a Node Content template I made after creating a new Content Type (which is infact an 'Apply' link, later to be say created in HTML5). I presume the Rules Link created the entity required into the DB fields as it injected into the Field type available when I looked at the Node Field profile to create new Fields and I presumed it would later work once I set the Rules operations. Anyway, having decided that my overall layout for the said Node was not really what I wanted (simply because I also want some dynamic Views to show on Panel areas) I realised that it was easier for me to edit one of the Node templates for content and create a 'Variant', that all worked fine and appears to be going in the right direction for my overall design and backend operation.

However, when I attempt to put any Rules Link now in the Node template Variant via the Panels designer, I cannot find any entity for reference to my created Rules Link. I presume it would merely be a show in any of the general Panels 'add content' (Panel->Layout->Edit Content) found in the left hand.

Am I a little bit at a loss to whether it's me or the backend doing something incorrect; Am I missing something here for adding Rules Links in the said Node Template 'Panels'?